# Login with FBSDK, cannot perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, segue, fbsdk

I have installed the **Facebook** **SDK**, followed all the requirements, it works as I can extract data from the user's Facebook account, however I cannot perform the segue once logged in.

I get an error message:

Warning: `Attempt to present <viewController1> on <FBSDKContainerViewController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Here are my codes:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil) {

        print("not logged in")
    }
    else {

        print("logged in")
    }


    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
}

 func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {


    if ((error) != nil)
    {

    }
    else if result.isCancelled {

    }
    else {

         if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work

            returnUserData()
            addViewHierarchy()

          //  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUpFollowPage", sender: self)


        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help ?
Thanks

Comment: Post the code which shows the login with FB.

Comment: I have added the corresponding codes. Thank you

Comment: Same problem, no "beautiful" solutions. Any advice on this?

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with the same problem (although I'm using `FBSDKLoginManager`'s `logInWithReadPermissions`).

Whilst the problem seems to be that the callback (or your `didCompleteWithResult` delegate call) is invoked before the Safari web view is dismissed, I can't find a nice solution.

My (horrific) answer has been to delay the segue, to give the `FBSDKContainerViewController` time to be dismissed naturally. In your case:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUpFollowPage", sender: self)
}
```

It may be possible to get away with a shorter delay.

This strikes me as a bug with the Facebook Login SDK. If I find time I might look at the [SDK source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Fortunately the App I'm working on is not due for release until the new year, so I'm hoping that the issue might be fixed in a later version anyway.

Comment: An improvement: Check whether `self.view.window` is `nil`. If it is not, you can perform the segue without any delay.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `viewDidAppear()` function and check the `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken` :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool){
  if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil{
     performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR_SEGUE",sender:self)
  }
}
```

Comment: viewDidAppear occurs once you load - but if from your VC you then launch the FB login dialog, upon its dismissal viewDid/WillAppear do not get called again (for me, in iOS13 at least). So this solution does not fly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while logging in with FB. Here is how I solved it. The issue is while navigating, the FBContainerView is still open. Using self.controller will refer to the FBContainerView and NOT the Topmost controller and hence no navigation. We will need to switch back to the top Most Controller and then perform the navigation.

You can do this without performing segue, by presenting view controller from top controller like this

```
let topController = self.topMostController()
topController.presentViewController(secondController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to get the top most controller define a method which will always return topmost controller

```
func topMostController()-> UIViewController {
    var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

    while((topController?.presentedViewController) != nil){
        topController = topController?.presentedViewController
    }
    if(topController != nil){
        return topController!
    }
    else{
        return self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to the ones above, but it is a bit more deterministic (and for me, safer).

This solution ensures we ARE the top most VC before presenting.

```
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01 / 30.0, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window, let rootVC = window.rootViewController {
                    var topController = rootVC
                    while let nextTop = topController.presentedViewController {
                        topController = nextTop;
                    }
                    if topController == self {
                        // we're good, go for it
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "afterLoginSegue", sender: nil)
                        timer.invalidate()
                    } else {
                        log.debug("waiting to transition until we're presenting...")
                    }
                } else {
                    log.error("couldn't resolve a key variable needed to segue, aborting.")
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            })
```

I still feel like there should be a way to get a callback once the presenting facebook login safari VC is gone, but until that solution comes along, this is as good as i can do (obviously this code could be cleaned up and modularized for use in multiple VCs, but you can just dump this in where needed).